# Can anyone tell the difference between these SharePoint Document Library Icons?

Tags: sharepoint

Can anyone tell me the difference between these 2 types of document library icons?  As far as I can tell, one was created in 2010 and the other 2013 maybe?

[image]

Comment: This question is better suited for [Sharepoint community](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This one is the **PowerPivot data librabry**, in default it let you preview documents in PowerPivot. Second one is standard doc lib.